# Ordering number of counts in ggplot histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram, ggplotly

I'm having the following data table `dt.test`:

```
dput(dt.test)
structure(list(Year = c(2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 
2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L, 2020L), GPNRPlan = c(100236L, 
111328L, 128003L, 130058L, 133874L, 135886L, 138153L, 142309L, 
151988L, 157024L, 158101L, 158757L, 163260L, 200324L, 200792L, 
207342L, 214062L, 217331L, 218005L, 218454L, 219836L, 238154L, 
254868L, 254869L, 254874L, 259947L, 264205L, 267717L, 282089L, 
283151L, 292166L, 306032L, 307995L, 330523L, 335787L, 348047L, 
348664L, 355409L, 363008L, 365676L, 368657L, 392114L, 394894L, 
395993L, 404010L, 500269L, 502879L, 515783L, 516704L, 613479L
), TB.Info = c("Below TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", 
"Below TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", "In TB", 
"Below TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "In TB", "Below TB", "In TB", 
"Below TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", 
"In TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Below TB", "In TB", 
"Below TB", "Below TB", "In TB", "In TB", "Over TB", "In TB", 
"Below TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", 
"Below TB", "Below TB", "Over TB", "Over TB", "Below TB", "In TB", 
"Below TB", "Below TB"), EV = c(0, 8991.71216732506, 0, 0, 952495.536027306, 
15787.4125389769, 5881.79901225216, 10020.1539658745, 29679.260860874, 
6623.90844477817, 19956.607049949, 10795.0898132095, 20110.9214012254, 
154265.744138562, 0, 18022.1733304456, 0, 46930.0874076566, 5031.92796650957, 
14766.994353086, 17428.2699502266, 1139.95904700027, 0, 0, 74480.5539097248, 
0, 0, 3125.39890360564, 41135.8019532497, 45455.901141461, 18068.8194807139, 
1574.19941919776, 71695.2819940052, 840619.522035336, 19137.7135190254, 
17462.2344585882, 6001.7267195835, 14056.3435516429, 0, 0, 51034.1108681587, 
2680.21093607705, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 897749.506753749, 7272.99092335283, 
-772.886617083522), EK = c(0, 8727.76940892211, 0, 0, 968654.154020939, 
15784.2477645437, 5852.58295283679, 10126.9467047725, 30178.7537734498, 
6452.5979909353, 19917.497780561, 10505.985181701, 20386.342324393, 
157344.902967186, 0, 18979.9946111749, 0, 45191.3139241601, 5152.46448254231, 
14606.1474532383, 17485.4003681122, 956.14494674998, 0, 0, 76242.2008458597, 
0, 0, 3271.78810230747, 43153.4577000728, 46305.3394606706, 18865.559964053, 
1676.38074270217, 73792.5743431249, 816694.588902057, 19259.8905579868, 
17273.9513316854, 5558.58747405537, 14081.8692372851, 0, 0, 53417.9083227921, 
2766.49603915519, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 925462.446710217, 7411.27949339667, 
-2269.10945132687), EH = c(0, -263.94275840295, 0, 0, 16158.6179936329, 
-3.16477443318076, -29.216059415372, 106.792738898008, 499.492912575829, 
-171.310453842869, -39.1092693880457, -289.10463150853, 275.420923167619, 
3079.15882862376, 0, 957.821280729258, 0, -1738.77348349646, 
120.536516032746, -160.84689984772, 57.13041788553, -183.814100250285, 
0, 0, 1761.64693613498, 0, 0, 146.38919870183, 2017.65574682313, 
849.438319209584, 796.740483339144, 102.181323504405, 2097.29234911977, 
-23924.9331332788, 122.177038961415, -188.283126902762, -443.139245528132, 
25.5256856422447, 0, 0, 2383.79745463335, 86.2851030781408, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 27712.9399564679, 138.288570043838, -1496.22283424335
), pBu = c(0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.05, 0.15, 0.05, 
0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.15, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 
0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.05, 
0.05, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1)), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Now I have constructed a `ggplot` histogram with `geom_histogram()` for the column `EV` with respect to the different tolerance band `pBu`:

```
EV <- (dt.test %>% dplyr::mutate(pBu = as.factor(pBu)) %>%
         ggplot(aes(x = EV)) +
         geom_histogram(aes(color = pBu, binwidth = 0.3), fill = "transparent") + 
         ggtitle("Histogram EV 2020") +
         ylab("Counts") +
         theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
               plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
               legend.title = element_blank(), 
               legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour ="black"),
               legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.box.margin = margin(t = 1, l = 1))
       
) %>%
  ggplotly()
```

This plot looks like this:

[image]

Now I'm wondering why the `pBu = 0.05` has higher bars than the green one? Because when I'm using the interactive tool of `plotly` I can see, that the red one (`pBu=0.05`) counts 4 and the green one (`pBu=0.1`) counts 25.

How can I order this correctly? When looking at plot, everybody would say that for `EV=0` we have more counts of `0.05` than of `0.1`, which is not correct.

Comment: Do you mean you want to change order of `pBu` in stacked histogram? Or if you mean just height of `pBu` is weird, that's normal in this case because it's stacked.

Comment: Yes the height is weird. I don't know why? 4 counts for ``pBu=0.05`` is here not plotted correctly

Comment: Because it's stacked. height of `pBu = 0.05` is `1+ 2+ 25 + 4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope these versions help you.

## unstacked histogram

```
(dt.test %>% dplyr::mutate(pBu = as.factor(pBu)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = EV)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(color = factor(pBu), binwidth = 0.3), fill = "transparent", alpha = 0.7, position = "dodge") + 
  ggtitle("Histogram EV 2020") +
  ylab("Counts") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour ="black"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.box.margin = margin(t = 1, l = 1)) 
) %>%
  ggplotly()
```

[image: unstack]

## Using `facet_wrap`

```
(dt.test %>% dplyr::mutate(pBu = as.factor(pBu)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = EV)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(color = factor(pBu), binwidth = 0.3), fill = "transparent", alpha = 0.7, position = "dodge") + 
  ggtitle("Histogram EV 2020") +
  ylab("Counts") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
        plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, hjust = 0.5, face = "bold"),
        legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white", size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour ="black"),
        legend.box.background = element_rect(colour = "black"), legend.box.margin = margin(t = 1, l = 1)) +
    facet_wrap(.~)
) %>%
  ggplotly()
```

[image: facet_wrap]